# Import pprint for every breakpoint()

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

Every time I use `breakpoint()` in python I inevitably end up importing `pprint` (`from pprint import pprint`). Is there a way to  automatically add `pprint` to the namespace whenever `breakpoint()` is reached?

Python 3.8.5

Similar questions that don't quite solve this problem or predate the implementation of `breakpoint()`

- [Automatically import modules when entering the python or ipython interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124578/automatically-import-modules-when-entering-the-python-or-ipython-interpreter)
- [Import pprint by default as a debugging tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208728/import-pprint-by-default-as-a-debugging-tool)
- [automatically import module when run python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255593/automatically-import-module-when-run-python-script/8255752#8255752)

Comment: I put the import in my watch variables in PyCharm.

Comment: If you weren't aware, you can use the [`pp` command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-pp), but that doesn't let you do things like `compact=True`.

Comment: @wjandrea - This is great!. I did not know that.

Comment: Type '?' in pdb to see the other commands avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a file like this, put it into an installable package if you want, or just drop it somewhere on the PYTHONPATH:

```
$ cat mybreakpoint.py 
import pdb

def pprint_breakpoint():
    import pprint
    pdb.set_trace()
```

Now you can use the env var [`PYTHONBREAKPOINT`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONBREAKPOINT) to customize the debugger scope like that:

```
$ PYTHONBREAKPOINT=mybreakpoint.pprint_breakpoint python3
Python 3.11.0b1 (main, May 18 2022, 12:50:35) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> breakpoint()
--Return--
> .../mybreakpoint.py(5)pprint_breakpoint()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) pprint.pprint({"k2":"v2", "k1":"v1"})
{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
```

Personally, I always install [IPython](https://ipython.org/) into my development environments, so that I can use `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=IPython.embed` and get a more full-featured REPL in breakpoints by default, including IPython's pretty printer.

Comment: Worked just as expected!